# MAUI Shell: How to add clickable item to TabBar or FlyoutItem?

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

I need to add item to TabBar (or FlyoutItem) that is similar to MenuItem in shell (just button with no ContentPage).

```
<FlyoutItem>
        <ShellContent Route="kitties" Title="Kitties" Icon="cat.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:GeneralAnimalPage}"/>

        <!-- something like this -->
        <SomeItem Title="Press me"  Click="Click_Handler"/>
        
        <!-- or this -->
        <Tab Title="Press me" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>

        <!-- or even this: no contenttemplate, just routing! -->
        <ShellContent Title="Press me"  Route="myroutepage1"/>


</FlyoutItem>
```

Getting ahead: I will need to add it programmatically in codebehind, and entry has to be in bottom bar.

Comment: That is impossible. You can't get the instance of the flyoutitem and tabbar in the shell in code behind. And the tab must have a content to display.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT If the code is placed in OnAppearing of the content page of the tab, how can it   go back to the previous page?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative, but actually working approach:

You can write your own TabBar, using BindableLayout and RadioButtons.

Good place to start: https://dev.to/davidortinau/making-a-tabbar-or-segmentedcontrol-in-net-maui-54ha